# sencha extjs data in multiple referenced grids

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, extjs, sencha-architect

I have two grids getting data from php mysql backend
First grid is display of all classes in a school. This represents 1 table of mysql. And I have no issues in displaying data
second grid gets data of students in a particular class, when one clicks on any of the class of first grid. Please see image below

[image]

This is a different table in mysql. And I am "ClassID" to php file. which sends sorted JSON of students of that particular class

i use the below code

var studentView = this.getstudentGrid;
var ClassData = record.get('ClassID');

```
        studentView.getStore().load({
           params:{ClassID: ClassData}

        });
```

but it says uncaught error and nothing gets displayed. Kindly help

Comment: yeah well ... I suggest you use console.log() to define where is the error... does studentView is pointing to an object? does ClassData ? console.log() them ...

Comment: other than pointing to the right objects ...  I think ClassID should be 'ClassID': ClassData

Comment: I agree with code4jhon, can you `console.log(studentView);` and add additional information regarding the response? Should it be `this.getStudentGrid();` (capital S)? Again, hard to tell the issue without more information. A fiddle would help as well.